# How to fix 'IndexError: index out of range'

Tags: python, blynk

I have built a simple app with Blynk. Unfortunately, I regularly get the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/pi/Desktop/Blynk/blynktest2.py", line 12, in <module>
    blynk.run()
  File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/BlynkLib.py", line 252, in run
    self.process(data)
  File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/BlynkLib.py", line 213, in process
    self.emit("int_"+args[1], args[2:])
IndexError: list index out of range
```

Even if I take out all code on my hardware and end up with the following code, the error comes up:

```
import BlynkLib

BLYNK_AUTH = 'MY_AUTH_IS_NORMALLY_HERE'    

# initialize blynk
blynk = BlynkLib.Blynk(BLYNK_AUTH)

while True:
    blynk.run()
```

I do not know exactly what causes the error, however, I noticed that the error occurs

- when the Blynk app is moved to the background
- when the screen of the mobile phone turns black
- the eror **does not** occur when normal disconnecting in the Blynk app via the stop button in the top right, and also not if reconnecting then

Comment: it's working properly in my system when tested.

Comment: Unfortunately not in my system, so I am thankful for any advice, why I am facing this error

Comment: Based on the above it looks like it's going out of range with the `args` being passed in?   Is it possible it's run differently when it's in the background?

Comment: I do not know. Unfortunately blynk.run() is a method from the BlynkLib, so I do not know, what they do. I personally did not implement any method changing the behavior when running in background

Answer (score -1):

This is one random issue which keeps happening. Try recreating the project by removing all the controllers or create a new project and update the authentication code in your code.